# How to scroll the diff buffer easily in Emacs while point is on the minibuffer

Tags: emacs, diff, cursor, scrolling

In Emacs, after a lot of editing, I press `C-x s` (save-some-buffers), then Emacs asks `"Save file ...? (y,n,.... d ...)"` for each file, I sometimes answer `d` (diff) to see the changes, but then it's not easy to scroll the diff buffer because the cursor is on the minibuffer. Scrollbar does not work. `C-M-v` works, but if I try to back-scroll by pressing `C-M-- C-M-v`, Emacs just says "Type C-h for help". How do I scroll the diff buffer in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To scroll up try <kbd>C-M-S-v</kbd> aka <kbd>C-M-V</kbd> (add <kbd>shift</kbd> to the sequence).